# Is there a memory leak when changing visual color from model plugin?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to change the visual of a mobile robot based on the state of the robot.
Though this works (i.e. the visual of the model changes to the desired color), the gazebo simulator starts to freeze.
When I delete the section of code that changes the model's colour, gazebo simulation works as normal (i.e. without freezing).

Please what am I doing wrong here?

This is the code snippet:

```
        gazebo::common::Color newColor(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
        msgs::Color *homColMsg = new gazebo::msgs::Color(gazebo::msgs::Convert(newColor));
        msgs::Color *homDiffMsg = new gazebo::msgs::Color(*homColMsg);
        gazebo::physics::LinkPtr link = this->model->GetLink("chassis");
        
        
        
        msgs::Visual visMsg = link->GetVisualMessage("visual");
        msgs::Material *materialMsg = visMsg.mutable_material();
        materialMsg->clear_ambient();
        materialMsg->clear_diffuse();
        
        visMsg.set_name(link->GetScopedName());
        visMsg.set_parent_name(this->model->GetScopedName());
        
        materialMsg->set_allocated_ambient(homColMsg);
        materialMsg->set_allocated_diffuse(homDiffMsg);
        
        this->pub_visual->Publish(visMsg);
```

The inspiration for this approach is from:
[handsim implementation](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/handsim/src/b6415df144217a6bf40b3f2265ae3ca079b89bfd/src/HaptixWorldPlugin.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#HaptixWorldPlugin.cc-1357%3C/p%3E)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17957/is-there-a-memory-leak-when-changing-visual-color-from-model-plugin?/) by [elcymon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2963/elcymon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-11-29**:
Interesting that on Handsim the link name is used on the visual message, I'd expect that to be the visual name. i.e. `model::link::visual` instead of `model::link`

**Comment by [elcymon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2963/elcymon/) on 2017-11-29**:
I changed it to 'model::link::visual' and it works fine now!
Thanks.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-11-29**:
Great! I added an answer so feel free to accept it and close the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As mentioned on the comments, the solution was to use the scoped visual name instead of the scoped link name.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0